# Disable Windows 10 swipe from left Gestures on a desktop with a touch screen

Tags: windows-10, gestures

We are building a kiosk system.  I have disabled everything but the swipe from the left.  By swiping from the left side of the screen they gain access to the start bar.  Is there a way to disable this in windows 10 standard.  Everything I have seen out there is detailing how to disable it on a laptop using their driver.  Our screen uses the default windows drivers which does not allow me to play with those settings.  Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yea im glad there is a duplicate question you found that is almost 2 years old and does not have an answer.

Comment: Doesn't make it a different question, and this linked duplicate may help it be discovered by someone who knows an answer. I'd suggest perhaps spending a bit of rep points and placing a bounty on the existing one to garner more attention.